# using word2vec.score.sg pair() raises Python error - only integers.....integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to implement `word2vec` in python to score the trained Skip-gram model on a pair of words. but I can't figure out the error:

> only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.

Here is the code I tried :

```
model = Word2Vec.load(r"C:\Users\Lenovo\model\word2vecforlaw.model")
z=gensim.models.word2vec.score_sg_pair(model, "patent", "law")
print(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need help understanding an error, you should share the full error stack you see: with all the info about exactly where the error occurred.

But also, the `score_sg_pair()` method does not take strings as the words, but the `Vocab` objects specific to the gensim `Word2Vec` model, per the documentation at:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.score_sg_pair

(These `Vocab` objects are found in the `model.wv.vocab` dictionary, keyed by the string words.)

Note also that these 'score' methods are only there to support a specific somewhat idiosyncratic way to use the model, further described in the paper and demo notebook linked from the docs for the `score()` method:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.score